# Simulate making library interfaces variant

Tags: c#, polymorphism, covariance, contravariance

There are several places where my code significantly benefits from using variance to take better advantage of polymorphism. What I would really like to do, which I know is not possible, is something like this:

```
abstract class A
{
    // In my perfect world, this would automatically define a compile-time type:
    // a super-type of IReadOnlyDictionary<Q, X>,
    // that only includes the members that obey the appropriate variance.
    // In the real world, this just doesn't compile.
    public abstract IReadOnlyDictionary<in Q, out X> Dict { get; }
}

class B : A
{
    // Q:R, and X:Y
    public Dictionary<R, Y> SubDict { get; private set; }
    public override IReadOnlyDictionary<in Q, out X> Dict { get { return SubDict; } }
}

class C : A
{
    // Q:S, and X:Z
    public Dictionary<S, Z> SubDict { get; private set; }
    public override IReadOnlyDictionary<in Q, out X> Dict { get { return SubDict; } }
}

foreach (A a in alist)
{
    Q q = new Q("test key");
    X x = a.Dict[key];
    Console.WriteLine(x.Information);
}
```

How can I achieve something like this? Here are some solutions I've come up with, but none of them is ideal.

1. Create an entirely independent interface tree with the separate base interfaces I want, and implement it with a subclass or wrapper class of Dictionary. Use those everywhere in my code instead of the library interfaces. Not ideal because my interfaces don't include the library versions of these interfaces, so they need to be converted or cast before passing them to a library method (this is more important with things like IList).
2. Include the library interfaces as bases of my interfaces at the appropriate point in the inheritance tree. Not ideal because this creates tons of ambiguity, which means I need to do a lot of casting in my code. On this note, is there a way to create an interface that inherits multiple members with the same name, and somehow mark them as being the same thing, so that implementers must provide a single implementation for both?
3. Somehow tell my code that the library interfaces implement mine. Not possible as far as I'm aware.

Code sample for Strategies 1 and 2:

```
public interface IReadOnlyDictionaryBase
{
    int Count { get; }
}

public interface IReadOnlyDictionaryKeyOut<out TKey> : IReadOnlyDictionaryBase
{
    IEnumerable<TKey> Keys { get; }
}

public interface IReadOnlyDictionaryValueOut<out TValue> : IReadOnlyDictionaryBase
{
    IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get; }
}

public interface IReadOnlyDictionaryKeyInValueOut<in TKey, out TValue> : IReadOnlyDictionaryValueOut<TValue>
{
    TValue this[TKey key] { get; }
    bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
    TValue GetValueTry(TKey key, out bool success);
}

// A disadvantage of Strategy 1 is that this is not related to the System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary.
// Strategy 2 attempts to reconcile this by adding IReadOnlyDictionary as a base interface here, but that results in ambiguity whenever I try to call one of the members.
public interface IExtendedReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IReadOnlyDictionaryKeyInValueOut<TKey, TValue>, IReadOnlyDictionaryKeyOut<TKey>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value);
}

public class ExtendedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IExtendedReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - you can't take an invariant interface and make it covariant (or contravariant) just by declaring it that way.  You could create a _new_ interface that _could be_ covariant or contravariant and use it to wrap an existing interface (like you mention in Option 1), but it's not clear exactly what you want to do with it.  Options 2 and 3 are not possible.

Comment: @DStanley I'm trying to get strategies, probably involving writing new interfaces, that will allow me to emulate what I did in my dream code sample. Basically I want to create a variant interface that contains a subset of the original interface's methods (the ones that support the variance as I defined it), but I keep running into either not being able to implement the original interface (strategy 1), or being stuck with a lot of ambiguity (strategy 2).

Comment: Well, you can't implement all of a variant interface with a variant one - you can implement only the _output_ methods in a covariant interface and all of the _input only_ methods in a contravariant interface, but if any methods have both inputs and outputs there's no way to put that in a variant interface.

Comment: @DStanley Right. The invariant interface descends from the variant ones. I've added a code sample that clarifies that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to take an invariant interface like `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and "declare it" as variant.  To be covariant, an interface must only ever *output* the generic type (like `IEnumerable<T>`).  So you can't simply take an invariant interface and make it variant just by declaring it that way.

Your option #1 is viable with caveats.  You *could* strip out the methods that *can't* be variant in a new interface and only expose the methods that match your variance needs, which would leave you with something like:

```
public interface IVariantReadOnlyDictionary<in TKey, out TValue>
{
    bool ContainsKey(TKey key);
    //bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value);  // cannot be contravariant in TValue

    TValue this[TKey key] { get; }

    //IEnumerable<TKey> Keys { get; }  // cannot be covariant in TKey
    IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get; }
    int Count { get; }  

    //cannot extend IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
}
```

Note that two methods of `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` cannot match your variance needs, and you cannot extend `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` in a variant manner.  You *could* cast to one of the variant methods in your client code but it would not be compile-time safe.

Note that you cannot:

- extend the "base" interface since it is not variant
- treat the base interfaces as yours (i.e. you can't safely cast an `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` to a `IVariantReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  You basically have to "wrap" an existing dictionary in a new type that implements this interface.

Comment: Thanks. I just clarified my original post: this is basically exactly what I was doing in Strategy 1. The question is more about whether it's possible to get around the pitfalls. My "perfect world" code sample was something that would do this automatically, which of course is not a feature of C#.

Comment: Nope; there's no way to make an invariant interface variant just by declaring it that way.